# Android Studio count how many days since application was last opened

Tags: android, count, calendar, days

This is just for a personal project, I'm creating a little basic journal with some other things. I have no idea where to begin I will be honest, but when my application launches I want it to display in a TextView how many days it has been since the application was last launched. Please can I get some help, a basic working example would be best but I will take any help I can get :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity `onCreate`, check `SharedPreferences` for the last used date, and display it if present.  Then save today's date.